# How can I list all sourced files in Zsh init process?

Tags: zsh, bindkey

I'm trying to use the Zsh plugin mcfly (or atuin), which is expected to `bindkey '^R'`, but it's not working in my computer, and when I check `bindkey` it shows:

```
"^R" history-incremental-search-backward
```

Seems my activate script `source <(mcfly init zsh)` is covered by some other (on-my-zsh?) plugins.

So I hope to check all possible sourced files to check the order of calls to `bindkey`, maybe something like:

```
ls-all-zsh-sourced-files | xargs rg 'bindkey'
```

But I don't know how to implement `ls-all-zsh-sourced-files` here.

I checked [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799445/show-all-sourced-files-in-zsh), and find I can get some useful information from `zsh -o SOURCE_TRACE`, but when I trying to use this mechanism to implement `ls-all-zsh-sourced-files` above, I failed, since `zsh -o SOURCE_TRACE` bring me to an interactive shell, and when I try `zsh -o SOURCE_TRACE -c 'echo ""'` it shows less file paths than before.

Any help?

Comment: What files are sourced by zsh is documented in the zsh man page. For finding what files are indirectly sourced (i.e. sourced from one of those initialization files), you would start zsh with the `-x` option and analyze the output.

Comment: `rg 'bindkey' ${^fpath}` seems useful，but still not complete for me，